# Сравнить список с ManyToMany в Django

Tags: python, django, compare

Дан список `members`. В нём содержаться экземпляры класса `User`. Нужно проверить все ли элементы данного списка являются элементами ManyToMany, в котором содержаться экземпляры того же самого класса `User`

**models.py:**

```
class Dialog(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, verbose_name="Участники диалога")
    messages = models.ManyToManyField(Message, blank=True, verbose_name="Сообщения")
```

**views.py:**

```
    members = [receiver.user, request.user]

    if Dialog.objects.filter(members=members): # Проверка на идентичность списков
        return redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 1):

Если для 1-го объекта, то соберите ID всех members и получите аналогичный список из Dialog.objects.get(id=some_id).members_set.values_list('id', flat=True).

Лучше даже не список, а множество.
Затем можете сравнивать эти значения. Очень удобно работать с множествами.

Также посмотрите про функции агрегации в Django, если не найдете подходящую функцию, то напишите свою, исходя от вашей БД.

Для PostgreSQL нужно смотреть в сторону операций с массивами, вроде `@>`. Этого будет достаточно